# After updating from 2.3.1 to 2.3.2, unable to export products

Tags: magento2, upgrade, export, magento2.3.2

After updating from version 2.3.1 to 2.3.2 community edition, I can not export products. The usual method - system - export, select entity type products, CSV format, fields enclosure checked, gives the message "Message added to the queue, wait to get your file soon" and nothing else. Below a file name called "email" appeared, and when I click download, blank page loads. Attempt to delete the file, and the following occurs:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): There are no export file with such name email

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): There are no export file with such name email
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:231]
#2 Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#3 Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Export\File\Delete\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#4 Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Export\File\Delete\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:143]
#5 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#6 Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Export\File\Delete\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#7 Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Export\File\Delete\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/ImportExport/Controller/Adminhtml/Export/File/Delete/Interceptor.php:26]
#8 Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Export\File\Delete\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:159]
#9 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:99]
#10 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#11 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#12 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#13 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#14 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:137]
#15 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#16 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case the files were being created with the wrong group. To fix this I ran the following (linux):

```
chmod g+s var/export
```

The `s` is the setuid bit and so files created in this directory will now inherit the same group.

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 777 var/export` works for me

Comment: Setting the permissions to 777 is always a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

We are experiencing the same issue. I noticed that the file is created correctly in var/export. However, it is created with insufficient permissions for download. Changing the permissions fixes the issue for the existing files. This doesn't help with future exports, though.

Any idea how to change the permissions for the generated files?

Answer (score 0):

Try running below command

```
php bin/magento queue:consumer:start exportProcessor
```

This command initiates the export processor consumer, which is responsible for handling product exports through the Magento message queue system.